# Can't configure karma to use karma-spec-reporter

Tags: automated-tests, karma-runner

In my karma.conf.js

```
plugins : [
  'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
  'karma-angular-filesort',
  'karma-coverage',
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor',
  'karma-spec-reporter',
],

coverageReporter: {
  type : 'html',
  dir : 'coverage/'
},

specReporter: {
  maxLogLines: 10,
  suppressPassed: false,
  suppressFailed: false,
  suppressSkipped: false,
  suppressErrorSummary: false
},

// reporters: ['progress']
reporters: ['spec']
```

Yet when I run my tests (gulp test), the output continues to be the same as when karma used the 'progress' reporter.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try running karma start --log-level debug (maybe pipe to a file for easier viewing). I found I had a type in the package's json file.